# Kerbals aren't respawning!

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I lost my 3 guys like... the day I bought the game. I have the respawn timer at 1 hour (I'm in sandbox) and its been a week (real time). I've read other answers, but they don't help. How do I bring them back?

Comment: What difficulty setting did you pick?

Comment: The setting is custom, really the only thing I changed was the crewmate respawn. (it's kind of ironic, isn't it?)

Comment: This one-hour setting is in-game hours, not real-life hours. Also see https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/388163/220080