# Why won't my Kerbal respawn?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

When I was going to land my rocket, the parachutes didn't work and the lander crashed and Bob Kerman died. I didn't know how long it would take for my kerbal to respawn so I waited for 2 months (in the game) for him to respawn but he didn't respawn.

I'm playing on sandbox with easy difficulty and I set it so that lost kerbals would come back.

Comment: how long did you wait irl?

Comment: about 2 hours...

Answer (score 1):

In KSP, the respawn time is based on real life time, not in-game time. The default time is 2 hours, though you can change it in the game settings down to 1 hour. If you have experience in tampering with the save and settings files, you could change it to 0 hours or something else via this method:

1. Make sure KSP is not running, and go to the `...\Kerbal Space Program\saves\NAME` directory, where `NAME` is the name of the savegame.
2. Next, go to the `GAME/PARAMETERS/DIFFICULTY/RespawnTimer` parameter. The unit here is in seconds.
3. Change the number (default `7200`) in any time amount you want! **NB: If you try to change this in-game afterwards, it will reset, and you will have to do the process again.**

I hope this helps in the revival of Bob!